# Extract PHP codes into Separate file

Tags: php, html

Can anyone help me to extract the following php codes into a separate file? Below is the code:

```php
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors', true);//Set this display to display  all erros while testing and developing the script
//////////////////////////////
require "config.php"; // Database Connection 

echo "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en\">
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo script from example.com</title>
</head>
<body>
";

echo "<input id=\"city\" list=\"city1\" >
<datalist id=\"city1\" >";

////  Collect options from table ///
$sql="select city from city ";  // Query to collect records
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo  "<option value=\"$row[city]\"/>"; // Format for adding options 
}
////  End of data collection from table /// 

echo "</datalist>";
?>

<center>
<br><br>a href='http://www.example.com' rel='nofollow'>example.com : Footer text.</a></center>

</body>

</html>
```

Below is the database connection file, just for reference:

```php
<?php
///////// Database Details , add  here  ////
$dbhost_name = "localhost";
$database = "test";  // Your database name
$username = "root";                  //  Login user id 
$password = "test";                  //   Login password
/////////// End of Database Details //////

//////// Do not Edit below /////////
try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}

?>
```

I just want to extract the PHP code in the main display page for a cleaner code structure.

Comment: It might be more obvious to the php experts in the room, but I'm a little unclear what you're asking.  Are you trying to take a block of php and put it in a separate file?  Which part?  It seems that you've already found the `require` keyword, which does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the way to do this is to put your HTML in a "template" and your PHP code in another file. You can use a full-featured template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [Plates](http://platesphp.com/simple-example/), or you can just place your HTML in a separate PHP file. Let's say your main file is called `myfile.php`. Make a new file called `myfile.template.php`.

In `myfile.php`:

```
<?php
require "config.php";

$cities = array();

$sql = "SELECT city FROM city";

foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row)
{
    $cities[] = $row['city'];
}

include('myfile.template.php');
```

In `myfile.template.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo script from example.com</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="city" list="city1" />
        <datalist id="city1" >
            <?php foreach ($cities as $city): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </datalist>

        <div align="center">
            <br><br>
            <a href='http://www.example.com' rel='nofollow'>example.com : Footer text.</a>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you , but can you give a brief explanation of your code.

Comment: No problem. What part? It's basically the same code you posted, split into two files. We include the `myfile.template.php`  from inside the main file, `myfile.php`. The only real difference is that we build the array `$cities` from the SQL results and then just use `$cities` inside the template.